# Why I can't check is div element loaded

Tags: jquery

How to check is DIV element loaded, I tried using this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slajder').loaded(function() {
      $('.carousel-caption').addClass('left-animation');
  });
}
```

Therefore, when my slide box DIV called .slajder loaded full 100%, I want to add class left-animation

Comment: There's no `loaded()` method in jQuery. DOM elements don't fire an event when they're loaded, except for certain elements that get remote content, like `img`, `script`, and `iframe`.

Comment: If you're using a slider plugin, it may have an event of its own that it triggers when it reaches 100%. Check its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check div element loading like this also

```
 if($('.slajder').length > 0){
  // Do something
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the DIV is loaded by .length property like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if( $('.slajder').length > 0) {
      //write your code here
  });
}
```